# AUIOClient_StartIO failing while play the song in background

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, spotify, avaudiosession

I have using the **Spotify iOS SDK** as streaming service to play the music. As I have to handle the interruption in the application so that I had integrated the **AVAudioSession** for the same.

Please find the below code.

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *audioSessionError = nil;
[session setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
               error: &audioSessionError];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(audioSessionInterruptionNotification:)
                                             name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification
                                           object:session];

-(void)audioSessionInterruptionNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {

//Check the type of notification, especially if you are sending multiple AVAudioSession events here
NSLog(@"Interruption notification name %@", notification.name);

if ([notification.name isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification]) {
    seccReason = @"Interruption notification received";

    //Check to see if it was a Begin interruption
    if ([[notification.userInfo valueForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan]]) {
        NSLog(@"Interruption began");

    } else if([[notification.userInfo valueForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded]]){
        NSLog(@"Interruption ended!");
        //Resume your audio
    }
  }
}
```

While testing the application on background I am getting the issue "**AUIOClient_StartIO failing**", so I had searched on google and found that it might be related to **AVAudioSession** **Category**, so I had changed it from **AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient** to **AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord**, but still I am getting the issue.

Please guide me what should I do change in order to accomplish it.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?